# JavaScript remove last History entries with same URL

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, server-side-rendering, history

I have a POST form (simple HTML, no JS involved in submission) which is partially validated server-side. When I submit it, server may return a redirect if there are any errors. Let’s say, the form is on `/myform` URI, but if the server found errors in data it will redirect to `/myform?error`. After this is done several times and finally correctly submitted, user may want to use his browser’s `back` button. But it makes user to go through all the steps of failed submission attempts, e.g. `/myform?success` -> `/myform?error` -> `/myform` -> `/home`.

How do I prevent this? My guess is to remove last `History` entries that have same URI. How do I achieve that? Or is there another better way? I use server side rendering with Spring (Java) so dynamic validation is not really an option for the use-case. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For security and privacy reasons, you can't view or modify a user's browser history.

However, if you're willing to use JavaScript, you can use the History API to replace the current page's state on successful submit:

```
history.replaceState(null, 'Page title', '/form-url');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Okay, but if I understand correctly, `replaceState()` doesn't remove excessive `back` button steps - only makes them have same URL. I already do that, but the users don't really like having to click more than a couple times to go back. Maybe I can somehow override the `back` button behaviour to always go back to a specific page... Doesn't really work well though as users may visit some forms from different pages.